# Session variables or new sql queries

Tags: php

I was wondering which is the most efficient.  Assigning 7 session variables when the user is logged in or passing the user ID and making new sql queries when the information is needed. I want to cater for mobile users with low download allowanaces as well and we don't have free wifi around here.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is all done server side so I don't think there are any considerations here for mobile users, other than the usual ones such as keeping the page downloads small and accessible.  In other words, the server resources are the bottleneck here, so go whichever way you like!  Generally speaking storing values (caching) is going to be faster in terms of processing, but could use more memory than fetching stuff as you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very helpful